# getting Exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException"

Tags: mysql, transactions, jms, xa, jboss-4.2.x

I am using **mysql 5.7 database** and **Jboss 4.2.3 application server**. I am using **managed connection** in our application and for **JMS messaging we use XA transaction**.

Our application support Oracle, MSSql Server and PostgreSQL database as well and we are using these databases with the same Jboss configuration and everything was working properly without any error.

But now we thought to use mysql5.7(latest) database as well with the same Jboss configuration. 
Now my problem is :

1. when we do any transaction(two phase commit) then when transaction gets committed and after that JMS messages start sending, till now it is ok but just after that it **throws exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException"**.

09:59:44,475 WARN  [loggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.preparefailed] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.preparefailed] XAResourceRecord.prepare - prepare failed with exception XAException.XAER_RMFAIL
09:59:44,476 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_50] - Prepare phase of action a002866:c34a:565e7368:d7 received heuristic decision: TwoPhaseOutcome.HEURISTIC_HAZARD
09:59:44,477 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_36] - BasicAction.End() - prepare phase of action-id a002866:c34a:565e7368:d7 failed.
09:59:44,480 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_37] - Received heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.HEURISTIC_HAZARD .
09:59:44,483 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_38] - Action Aborting
09:59:44,557 ERROR [SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.handleEndTransactionException(TxPolicy.java:198)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:184)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:103)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:221)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:466)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:284)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:201)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:134)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1397)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:135)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:87)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:175)
        ... 40 more

Because of that we are not able to proceed further.

I am trying to fix it from previous some of the days.Also I researched so many links, websites, blogs but doesn't work for me. I tried everything but not able to fix the problem.

It is something that is causing the problem from the **XA Transaction** but not able to identify the exact reason why it is ?

I have **only replaced the previous database to mysql5.7**. With other databases it is working fine.

please help me out to find out the exact cause of this exception and solution as well. Thank you so much in advance